# HDMI version on Gigabyte GA-H55-UD3H / Intel H55?

Tags: hdmi, gpu

I am looking for information regarding the HDMI standard for the Gigabyte GA-H55-UD3H motherboard. All the sites simply say that the motherboard has an HDMI interface but they do not show its version.

I am interested to know if it supports the version 1.4 standard (for display of 3D content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 1.0 and 1.3 Motherboard revisions, the HDMI is 1.3.

[Link to Gigabyte article](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=1456&pid=3504).

It is unlikely that onboard HDMI supports 3D graphics. You'll probably have to get a dedicated graphics card for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I kept looking into the motherboard specs and also searching intel site.. next time I know where to look.